# Is chaining functions like doX(doY(doZ(data))) poor practice?

Tags: javascript

I've noticed a lot of my code ends up looking like:

```
doX(doY(doZ(data)))
```

Is there any thing wrong with this?

Comment: this style is very common in functional programming (which javascript supports) and is meaningfull

Comment: What is the alternative you are comparing it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d consider this good practice - it encourages [Curly’s law](https://blog.codinghorror.com/curlys-law-do-one-thing/) (every function should do one thing), allowing you to reuse parts of the function chain later in different circumstances.

If you find the chains get too long and start feeling cumbersome, just break somewhere logical and assign a variable *with a meaningful name*:

```js
const almostResult = doY(doZ(data));
return doX(almostResult);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with it, as long as your code is readable and easy to work with.

**The functional approach**

If you want to code in a more functional style, I recommend you use `compose` form lodash or ramda. It takes the result from one function and pipes it into the next one (starting on the right hand side).

```
import { compose } from 'ramda';
...
const doAll = compose(doX, doY, doZ);
const result = doAll(data);
```

I recommend [Professor Frisby's Mostly adequate guide to Functional Programming](https://github.com/MostlyAdequate/mostly-adequate-guide), for why this is a cool way to program (See chapter 5 for compose).

**Ecmascript pipes is coming (maybe)**

In the not to distant future we will hopefully get the [pipe operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator) (`|>`), which will give the language itself a very elegant way to combine functions.

```
const result = data
  |> doZ
  |> doY
  |> doX
```